# Background Color for div Not Displaying Once Uploaded

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I made some changes to code that added a new div for a certain block of text. When viewing the HTML file in Chrome, it displays perfectly. But once I uploaded it to my web hosting service, I found out it displays without the background color for that div (and only that div). Seems to display correctly using Chrome on my phone, however. I currently have both the website itself and the HTML file open side by side and can't figure out how this happened.

CSS for div not working:

```
#indexbar {
    background-color: rgba(176,224,230, 80%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
```

CSS for div working:

```
#main {
    padding: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
    background-color: rgba(176,224,230, 80%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 0 5em 0 5em;
}
```

Edit: added HTML for broken code

```
<div id="indexbar">
<h4><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a> | <a href="resume.html">RESUME</a> | <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working here! change the position to relative instead of fixed

```
#indexbar {
    background-color: rgba(176,224,230, 80%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chandirasekaranid/5Ldfm8qu/

please clear the file cache and try!!

Comment: Clearing the cache fixed it, thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `background-color: rgba(176,224,230, 80%) !important`; sometimes this may happen when other styles overwrites the background color.

Comment: I just tried that, but it doesn't seem to have helped. Thank you for the !important tip though, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

you just provide `height` to `div` or add some text content, then it will work. by default a div element take `0px` height. 
check updated snippet below..

```css
#indexbar {
    background-color: rgba(176,224,230, 80%);
    border-radius: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="indexbar">
<h4><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a> | <a href="resume.html">RESUME</a> | <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></h4>
</div>
```

Comment: The div does have text in it, but I tried added height to the CSS and it's still not displaying correctly once uploaded. The text is there but the background isn't showing.

Comment: I added it to the body of the post, but I'll put it here as well for you

`<div id="indexbar">
<h4><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a> | <a href="resume.html">RESUME</a> | <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></h4>
</div>`

Comment: @KatieB check updated answer. it's working fine in given snippet

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your CSS is correctly linked to your HTML ??
Otherwise try to replace the 80% by .8